# Problems with JWT and .identify in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have *forked* this: https://github.com/ammarnadeeem/diaryExpress-react-flask-mysql and I have some problems with reactjs and getting the profile information when I try to login to a user account.
In my MySQL the user, password, email and so on is registered, but it seems like there is an error with a token.
Here is my code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.usertoken;
    const { identity } = jwt_decode(token);
    this.setState({
      first_name: identity.first_name,
      last_name: identity.last_name,
      email: identity.email,
    });
  }
```

Her is the error:

```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined
> Profile.componentDidMount src/components/Profile.js:22   19 | const
> token = localStorage.usertoken;   20 | const { identity } =
> jwt_decode(token);   21 | this.setState({
> > 22 |   first_name: identity.first_name,   23 |   last_name: identity.last_name,   24 |   email: identity.email,   25 | }); View
> compiled ▶ 17 stack frames were collapsed. ./src/index.js
> src/index.js:7    4 | import App from './App';    5 | import
> registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';    6 | 
> >  7 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));    8 | registerServiceWorker();    9 |    10 |  View compiled ▼ 6 stack
> frames were expanded.
> __webpack_require__ /home/basileus/diaryExpress-react-flask-mysql/webpack/bootstrap
> 2773a34b4f4e3e36f9f0:678 fn
> /home/basileus/diaryExpress-react-flask-mysql/webpack/bootstrap
> 2773a34b4f4e3e36f9f0:88 0
> http://193.69.47.200:3000/static/js/bundle.js:76680:18
> __webpack_require__ /home/basileus/diaryExpress-react-flask-mysql/webpack/bootstrap
> 2773a34b4f4e3e36f9f0:678 (anonymous function)
> /home/basileus/diaryExpress-react-flask-mysql/webpack/bootstrap
> 2773a34b4f4e3e36f9f0:724 (anonymous function)
> http://193.69.47.200:3000/static/js/bundle.js:728:10 ▲ 6 stack frames
> were expanded. This screen is visible only in development. It will not
> appear if the app crashes in producti
```

Answer (score 0):

Something with the { identity } - so you need to sort it in another way?

Comment: Session instead of local?

Answer (score 0):

For now it is { identity } - but why use {}.
Take them away, and I think it would work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode).

```
var decoded = jwt_decode(token);
 
console.log(decoded);
 
/* prints:
 * { foo: "bar",
 *   exp: 1393286893,
 *   iat: 1393268893  }
 */
```

Hence you should be using

```
const identity = jwt_decode(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Salazar for answering:

> For now it is { identity } - but why use {}. Take them away, and I
> think it would work.

This was the problem.